# Database is only outputting one word from the row

Tags: php, sql, web, phpmyadmin

```html
<?php 
      if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
                  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                      $fName = $row['firstName'];
                      $sName = $row["lastName"];
                      $email = $row["email"];
                      $address1 = $row['address1'];
                      $address2 = $row["address2"];
                      $address3 = $row["address3"];
                      $city = $row["city"];
                      $county = $row["county"];
                      $postcode = $row["postcode"];
                      $country = $row["country"];
                      $mobile = $row["mobile"];
                      $homeNum = $row["home"];
                      
                      
             }
                  }
      ?>
      
      <?php 
      
           <label for="subject">Address 1:</label>
<input type="text" id="lname" name="address1" size ="40" value=<?php echo $address1 ?>> <br>
```

I want the form to have the value "address1" that is in the db. It is meant to echo out "27 Lisburn Road" from the db row "address1" in the form value, however, only "27" appears in the form on the webpage.

When I echo out $address1 not in the form, the full address is outputted on the webpage(i.e - 27 Lisburn Road).

So in conclusion, I am very confused because when I echo $address1 as the form value, only "27" is outputted on the webpage, but outside the form "27 Lisburn Road" is outputted when $address1 is echoed.

Anyone know how I can solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You need quotes arround the value attribute. Otherwise it ends at the first space.

Comment: I would try to var_dump($row) and see what the data look like.  What exactly have you tried? I'm assuming you know for sure that the table contains the full string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make sure that the table data for Address 1 is set to CHAR in your mysql table instead of an integer or anything else? This could be why.

Try this:

```
<?php 
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $fName = $row["firstName"];
      $sName = $row["lastName"];
      $email = $row["email"];
      $address1 = $row["address1"];
      $address2 = $row["address2"];
      $address3 = $row["address3"];
      $city = $row["city"];
      $county = $row["county"];
      $postcode = $row["postcode"];
      $country = $row["country"];
      $mobile = $row["mobile"];
      $homeNum = $row["home"];                          
    }          
?>

<label for="subject">Address 1:</label>
<input type="text" id="lname" name="address1" size ="40" value="<?php echo $address1; ?>"> <br>

<?php } else { ?>

<label for="subject">Address 1:</label>
<input type="text" id="lname" name="address1" size ="40" value="test"> <br>

<?php } ?>
```

Your PHP will have an independent execution context over your HTML if you don't close off statements before ending the PHP like so ?>

Comment: yeah man its set to varchar, so it should be ok? Or am I incorrect?

Comment: Also try trimming like Elin said below.

Comment: You also needed to include quotations around your value, my code should work for you now.

Comment: Yes that's it, That's worked great, I appreciate your help Zach!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to see if you should remove any blank spaces or just `trim($address1)`.